# Set word wrap for plain text only

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want word wrap off for everything except plain text.

I've added `"word_wrap": false` to my `Preferences.sublime-settings` and then created `Plain Text.sublime-settings`.

`Plain Text.sublime-settings` is in `...AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` and contains:

```
{
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

However, the pain text file remains unwrapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set settings for a specific language, do the following:

1. Open up any file with that syntax type
2. Go to *Preferences –> Settings–More –> Syntax Specific–User*

This should open up the correct file for your language-specific preference settings.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text is **case sensitive** on the file name.

`Plain Text.sublime-settings`  <== Bad

`Plain text.sublime-settings`  <== Good

`

Comment: An easier and better way to go to the right file is to open some file that has the syntax-type you want to add settings for (in this case, Plain Text) and then in the menu navigate to *Preferences –> Settings–More –> Syntax Specific–User*, and the correct settings file will open up.

Comment: @saadq i didn't know about that.  If you'd like to add it as an answer then I'll tick it.